# How to add .NET 5 to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 and it already has .NET Core 2 package. Can I add .NET 5 to it? If yes how can I do that?

Comment: .NET 5 is installed with Visual Studio 2019, not 2017

Comment: No, and you can consider switching to a newer VS version and newer .NET too

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mre]". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, what did you do to test what you learned? What is the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem? Without that, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [.net downloadpage](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0) ,select your version,and check visual studio support:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the .NET Core 5 SDK from the Microsoft website. Link is below.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/5.0